# having problems to adding data into DB from register.php

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

I am new to PHP and I am doing some school work and facing some issues. I am not able to add data from my register.php into my DB which is hosted in xampp. and the funny thing is that the register.php keeps refreshing. Kindly please help. Not sure where is there error. I have checked on the php.ini file as well and had turn on the error error_reporting=E_ALL.

This my code:

Register.php:

```
<?php
include("config.php");
$title=$_REQUEST['sel1'];
$fname=$_REQUEST['t1'];
$lname=$_REQUEST['t2'];
$gen=$_REQUEST['r1'];
$id=$_REQUEST['t3'];
$pass=$_REQUEST['p1'];
$phone=$_REQUEST['t5'];
$add=$_REQUEST['t6'];
$city=$_REQUEST['t7'];
$coun=$_REQUEST['t8'];
$dob=$_REQUEST['t9'];
if($_REQUEST['sub'])
{
$sel=mysqli_query("select id from register where id='$id' ");
$arr=mysqli_fetch_array($sel);


}
if($arr['id']!=$id)
  {
   if($_POST['sub'])
   mysqli_query("insert into register ('$title','$fname','$lname','$gen','$id','$pass','$phone','$add','$city','$coun','$dob')")
       {

         echo "<script>location.href='index.php?con=13 & wel=$id'</script>";
       }
     }
else
{
echo "user already exists";
}

}
?>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function fnam()
{
  var fnam=/^[a-zA-Z]{4,15}$/;
   if(document.f1.t1.value.search(fnam)==-1)
    {
     alert("enter correct  first name");
     document.f1.t1.focus();
     return false;
     }
    }

     function lnam()
{
  var lnam=/^[a-zA-Z]{4,15}$/;
   if(document.f1.t2.value.search(lnam)==-1)
    {
     alert("enter correct last name");
     document.f1.t2.focus();
     return false;
     }
    }

function email()
{
 var email=/^[a-zA-Z0-9-_\.]+@[a-zA-Z]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}$/;
   if(document.f1.t3.value.search(email)==-1)
    {
     alert("enter correct email");
     document.f1.t3.focus();
     return false;
     }
    }

    function pass()
    {
    var pass=/^[a-zA-Z0-9-_]{6,16}$/;
   if(document.f1.p1.value.search(pass)==-1)
    {
     alert("enter correct pass");
     document.f1.p1.focus();
     return false;
     }
     }
    function phone()
    {
    var phn=/^[0-9]{9,14}$/;
  if(document.f1.t5.value.search(phn)==-1)
    {
     alert("enter correct phone no");
     document.f1.t5.focus();
     return false;
     }
     }

    function add()
    {
    var add=/^[a-zA-Z0-9- ]{10,150}$/;
  if(document.f1.t6.value.search(add)==-1)
    {
     alert("enter correct address");
     document.f1.t6.focus();
     return false;
     }
     }

     function city()
     {
     var city=/^[a-zA-Z]{5,30}$/;
     if(document.f1.t7.value.search(city)==-1)
    {
     alert("enter correct city");
     document.f1.t7.focus();
     return false;
     }

     }
      function coun()
     {
     var city=/^[a-zA-Z]{5,30}$/;
     if(document.f1.t8.value.search(city)==-1)
    {
     alert("enter correct country");
     document.f1.t8.focus();
     return false;
     }

     }

function vali()
{
  var nam=/^[a-zA-Z]{4,15}$/;
   var email=/^[a-zA-Z0-9-_\.]+@[a-zA-Z]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}$/;
    var pass=/^[a-zA-Z0-9-_]{6,16}$/;
        var phn=/^[0-9]{9,14}$/;
      var add=/^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]{10,150}$/;
      var city=/^[a-zA-Z]{5,30}$/;

   if(document.f1.t1.value.search(nam)==-1)
    {
     alert("enter correct  first name");
     document.f1.t1.focus();
     return false;
     }

  else if(document.f1.t2.value.search(nam)==-1)
    {
     alert("enter correct last name");
     document.f1.t2.focus();
     return false;
     }

  else if(document.f1.t3.value.search(email)==-1)
    {
     alert("enter correct login name");
     document.f1.t3.focus();
     return false;
     }



   else if(document.f1.p1.value.search(pass)==-1)
    {
     alert("enter correct pass");
     document.f1.p1.focus();
     return false;
     }


      else if(document.f1.t5.value.search(phn)==-1)
    {
     alert("enter correct phone no");
     document.f1.t5.focus();
     return false;
     }


  else if(document.f1.t6.value.search(add)==-1)
    {
     alert("enter correct address");
     document.f1.t6.focus();
     return false;
     }




    else if(document.f1.t7.value.search(city)==-1)
    {
     alert("enter correct city");
     document.f1.t7.focus();
     return false;
     }

        else if(document.f1.t8.value.search(city)==-1)
    {
     alert("enter correct country");
     document.f1.t8.focus();
     return false;
     }

     else
    {
     return true;
     }
     }


</script>
</head>
<body>


<div><br/><center><h2><font face="Lucida Handwriting" size="+1" color="#00CCFF">Register Yourself</font></h2></center></div>
<div>
<div style="width:25%;float:right">
<br><br><br><br><br>
<img src="usepics/7.jpg">
</div>
<br><br>
<center><div style="width:70%;float:right" align="center">
<fieldset style="background:#CC99CC;width:50%">
<br><br>
<form method="post" name="f1" onSubmit="return vali()">
<table width="366" border="0" align="center">

  <tr>
    <td><div align="center"><strong><font size="+1" face="Comic Sans MS">Title:</font></strong></div></td>
    <td><label>
      <select name="sel1" id="sel1">
        <option value="Mr.">Mr.</option>
        <option value="Ms.">Ms.</option>
        <option value="Mrs.">Mrs.</option>
      </select>
    </label></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="164"><div align="center"><font size="+1" face="Comic Sans MS"><b> First&nbsp;Name:</b></font></div></td>
    <td width="192">

        <input name="t1" type="text" id="t1" onChange="return fnam()">    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><div align="center"><font size="+1" face="Comic Sans MS"><strong>Last name:</strong></font></div></td>
    <td><input name="t2" type="text" id="t2" onChange="return lnam()" ></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><div align="center"><font size="+1" face="Comic Sans MS"><b>&nbsp;Gender:</b> </font></div></td>
    <td><input name="r1" type="radio" value="male">
      <strong>Male</strong>
        <input name="r1" type="radio" value="female">
        <strong>Female</strong></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><div align="center"><font size="+1" face="Comic Sans MS"><b>&nbsp;Enter Email : </b></font></div></td>
    <td><input name="t3" type="text" id="t3" onChange="return email()"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><div align="center"><font size="+1" face="Comic Sans MS"><b>&nbsp;Choose a  Password:</b> </font></div></td>
    <td><input name="p1" type="text" id="p1" onChange="return pass()"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr> <td><div align="center"><font size="+1" face="Comic Sans MS"><b>Phone no: </b></font></div></td>
    <td><input name="t5" type="text" id="t5" onChange="return phone()"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><div align="center"><font size="+1" face="Comic Sans MS"><strong>Address:</strong></font></div></td>
    <td><label>
      <textarea name="t6" id="t6" value="return add()"></textarea>
    </label></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><div align="center"><font size="+1" face="Comic Sans MS"><strong>City:</strong></font></div></td>
    <td><input name="t7" type="text" id="t7" onChange="return city()"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><div align="center"><font size="+1" face="Comic Sans MS"><strong>Country:</strong></font></div></td>
    <td><input name="t8" type="text" id="t8" onChange="return coun()"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><div align="center"><strong><font size="+1" face="Comic Sans MS">Date of Birth: </font></strong></div></td>
    <td><label>
      <input name="t9" type="text" id="t9">
    </label></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2"><label><br>
    <center>
      <input name="sub" type="submit" id="sub" value="Create my Account">
    </center>
    </label></td>
    </tr>

</table>
 </form>

</fieldset>
</div>
</center>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Config.php

```
<?php
mysqli_connect("localhost","root","");
mysqli_select_db("shop");
?>
```

Comment: Where is the insert query

Comment: This code is vulnerable to sql injection or simple syntax errors due to not escaped arguments and unnecessary complex: instead of two queries you could simply perform the `insert` directly and simply react on the error raised by the violation of the unique constraint on the primary key in the `register` table. So no need for the first `select` query _at all_.

Answer (score 0):

**correct your insert query**

```
mysqli_query("insert into register 
(field_name1,field_name2,field_name3,field_name4,field_name5,field_name6,field_name7,field_name8,field_name9,field_name10,field_name11) 
values
('$title','$fname','$lname','$gen','$id','$pass','$phone','$add','$city','$coun','$dob')");
```

**replace field_name with the column of register table**

Comment: hi have tried it but still no use. But this time when i add the comments mysqli_query("insert into register 
(field_name1,field_name2,field_name3,field_name4,field_name5,field_name6,field_name7,field_name8,field_name9,field_name10,field_name11) 
values
('$title','$fname','$lname','$gen','$id','$pass','$phone','$add','$city','$coun','$dob')");  when i click on the register page it comes out a blank page.